# Lighttpd send Nagios command-line output instead of web interface

Tags: nagios, lighttpd, cgi

I recently installed Nagios on an EC2 instance running AmazonLinux (which is basically SuSe, to my understanding). I'm using `lighttpd` and `mod_cgi` to serve the web interface.

When I navigate to a page, instead of getting the actual content, I get this:

```
Nagios Core 3.3.1
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 07-25-2011
License: GPL

Website: http://www.nagios.org
Usage: /usr/sbin/nagios [options] 

Options:

  -v, --verify-config          Verify all configuration data
  -s, --test-scheduling        Shows projected/recommended check scheduling and other
                               diagnostic info based on the current configuration files.
  -x, --dont-verify-paths      Don't check for circular object paths - USE WITH CAUTION!
  -p, --precache-objects       Precache object configuration - use with -v or -s options
  -u, --use-precached-objects  Use precached object config file
  -d, --daemon                 Starts Nagios in daemon mode, instead of as a foreground process

Visit the Nagios website at http://www.nagios.org/ for bug fixes, new
releases, online documentation, FAQs, information on subscribing to
the mailing lists, and commercial support options for Nagios.
```

Which appears to be the help document for the command-line version. Here's the relevant bit of my `lighttpd.conf`:

```
alias.url = (
                "/nagios/cgi-bin" => "/usr/sbin/nagios",
                "/nagios" => "/usr/share/nagios/html"
)

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/nagios/cgi-bin" {
        cgi.assign = ( "" => "" )
}

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/nagios/cgi-bin" {
        auth.backend = "htpasswd"
        auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/etc/nagios/passwd"
        auth.require = ( "" => (
                "method" => "basic",
                "realm" => "Nagios Access",
                "require" => "user=nagiosadmin"
                )
        )
}

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/nagios" {
        auth.backend = "htpasswd"
        auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/etc/nagios/passwd"
        auth.require = ( "" => (
                "method" => "basic",
                "realm" => "Nagios Access",
                "require" => "user=nagiosadmin"
                )
        )
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/sbin/nagios`? `grep mod_cgi /path/to/lighttpd.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. To people who find this on Google or whatever:

For some reason, the cgi-bin directory is actually installed in `/usr/lib64/nagios/`. I was pointing lighttpd at the actual executable for Nagios, which was why it was spitting out its help doc.

This is the section that needs to be changed:

```
alias.url = (
                "/nagios/cgi-bin" => "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi-bin",
                "/nagios" => "/usr/share/nagios/html"
)
```